# Inserting a Tee In 1" Pipe for an Air Compressor?

Tags: plumbing, copper, compressor, winterizing

I have a copper pipe outside my house that is 1" in diameter (Measured 1.1 inches using a digital caliper) that feeds our house's sprinkler system.

My dad uses his commercial air compressor to clear the sprinkler lines of water for the winter so they don't freeze.

Unfortunately to do this he usually removes the glass pane from the basement window which takes forever. We came up with the idea to cut the copper pipe outside and solder a fitting to the part of the pipe outside.

My question is what kind of tee should I look for that unions 1"-1" copper pipe and leaves a cap-able (When not being used) inlet for the air compressor?

My initial thought was something like a 1" - 1" - 1/2" tee similar to ([https://www.amazon.com/Libra-Supply-options-Fitting-Plumbing/dp/B01M1GAH5K/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?keywords=1+inch+copper+tee+reducer+ftp&qid=1554238142&s=gateway&sr=8-1-fkmr0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M1GAH5K)), but I'm not sure about how this would union with an air compressor hose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider something like this. These are just pieces I have laying around. All are common, easy to source and inexpensive. The fitting in your link will work as well, you would just follow with a valve and a air tool fitting.

[image]

*this is another way*

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer Joe, I have lots of pipe around and would have just described it. The OP should accept your answer I doubt there is a better way.

Comment: @EdBeal you could probably tighten it up with a 1/2" sweat - 1/4" npt bushing, 1/4" nipple, valve and male air tool fitting. My garage is a disaster right now and couldn't find everything. And I don't think I have the bushing. Some of those are a little bit specialty the methods pictured are big box off the shelf.

Comment: Excellent suggestion using a valve. Our current set up involved a galvanized threaded cap which was screwed into place.